# Mapping NativeQuery results into a POJO using spring jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-mapping, spring-repositories, hibernate-native-query

I have Tables A, B and C. All three of them have respective Spring repository interfaces. But I am just using the Table C to retrieve some values from A and some from B using a huge query on top of one of the repository methods in my ICRepository interface class.

I am not really storing any information in table C.

Is there a way I can delete the table C in Oracle and just use a class C as pojo to retrieve the information.

Comment: Create a database view C based on your huge query against A and B. Map an entity  to the view. Create a repository for this entity.

Comment: Looking for a way without using database views...